# Meaning: deliberate vs ponder

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm doing some exercises and don't understand why in the sentence below "deliberate" is the right answer whereas "ponder" has similar meaning:

> The jury are still **deliberating**, but they're expected to reach a
>   verdict soon.

Thanks for you thoughts.

Comment: The dictionary does not seem to back me up, but I think of *deliberating* as *pondering* in order to decide/choose something.

Comment: It's simply a fixed expression. There's no particular reason to it. Juries deliberate. In fact, the verb deliberate is seldom seen in any other context.

Comment: Good question, but next time please Google the definitions first and then we'll help you clear your doubts. :)

Answer (score 2):

In a Biblical context, the word ponder was used to describe the process of clearing a path of obstacles such as large rocks so that a royal procession could proceed without breakdown. Verses that refer to this process are in Proverbs 4:26 "Ponder the path of your feet, then all your ways will be sure".
Also in Isaiah 40:3 describes the process: "In the wilderness prepare the way of the Lord. Make straight in the desert a highway for our God". The double meaning is implied that if you mentally remove the obstacles of your thinking such as fear, anger, prejudice or bias, then a decision is easier made. Therefore to "ponder" is to carefully remove the obstacles keeping you from thinking clearly. A process of elimination.

Comment: 1. "ponder" was not used in Biblical times, because English did not exist then.  2. Some other translations of Proverbs 4:26 suggest that the meaning of the word used there is along the lines of the modern definition of "ponder", not the one you propose.  3. If you want me to buy any of this, you'll need to cite an authority.

Comment: Tracing the KJB usage has value also, particularly for English usages.

Comment: Looking online, it seems bparker is citing [ESV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Standard_Version), KJB Proverbs 4:26 goes: "Ponder the path of thy feet, and let all thy ways be established."  "[pal·lês](http://biblehub.com/text/proverbs/4-26.htm)" is Hebrew for balance (a scale), and English "ponder" comes from the same Latin roots as pendulum et al., but centuries later "ponder"'s a bit of a dead metaphor, perhaps it gained some watery calms from Middle English's "pond".

Comment: I do understand that "ponder" is not a Hebrew word.Still, the word "ponder" in this context denotes an action of sorts that seems to be more than just thinking hard but rather a process of thought. There are more verses than just this one that uses the English "ponder" in a context of taking careful steps. Perhaps "balance" is appropriate in describing that. While I may not be able to prove exact etymology I stand by the concept of the definition based on its usage here. But I also will dig deeper from older texts to see if my definition holds.

Answer (score 1):

*Deliberate* implies alertness, time limits, some definite decision to be made, perhaps using rules or formula, and a situation that calls for it, as with juries.

*Ponder* lacks those things, and is unscheduled, not routine, perhaps even involuntary (though seldom unwanted), a mind facing nature or the consequences of some natural event, appreciating the relative magnitudes of objects and events and memories, as if watching a storm go by.

Pondering thought *feels* slow, but the physical duration needn't be, one might ponder in a single second, before or while falling from a height.  Deliberation feels more like clockwork, and ends like a short passenger trip, "your stop is here".